# 12.04 performing worse than 11.10

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, nvidia

For what reason, do you think, 12.04 performs worse than 11.10? I recently fresh-installed 12.04 and have found that the general screen animations (like swiping between desktops, window fading, etc) are noticeably stickier than 11.10, under the same conditions.

Overall, 12.10 is superior to 11.10, so I'm not complaining. But the generally worse Compiz smoothness is somewhat irritating. It's not unbearable, but it's certainly not smooth at times.

At times. Not always. For example, if I move between desktops, then the first one or two animations are bumpy. After that, it's fine. It's as if the animations need "warming up". Of course, if I don't move between desktops for a while, then it becomes bumpy again.

Could it be because my Nvidia graphics cards (I have two) are running as "adaptive"?

Comment: For me 10.10 worked the "Smoothest" with a bunch of compiz effects that made the desktop environment Awesome!  I am still getting used to 12.04.

Comment: The question is better suited to a forum than AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this would help you or not, but try it and let me know if it makes a difference. I have this on my NVIDIA config to always force the power usage on my card to stay at Performance and not fluctuate between various power levels.

1. Open a Terminal:
2. sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
3. Under Device Add:

   Option "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerEnable=0x1; PerfLevelSrc=0x2222;
   PowerMizerDefault=0x1; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x1"

Good luck.

Comment: It tells me that "You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file." What would the sudo command be?

Comment: @gonzoza tried it with `gksu` in front of the command.

Comment: After I made the change, I saved the file over the one that was there. I re-did the process, just to check, and on opening the text file, it is now completely empty. Nothing seems broken, but is the empty xorg.conf file expected behaviour?

Comment: That usually happens when a typo is made on the path (ie: typing ect instead of etc/X11/... etc, etc. It may be that you have to write the initial xorg.conf within the NVidia server settings.

Comment: The sudo command is sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Answer (score 4):

If you're running the 295.40 version of the Nvidia driver (`apt-cache policy nvidia-current` should show you) and you're using older Nvidia hardware - this is a known issue.

295.40 was released to address a security issue in the .33 version but this also had a major impact on performance. Nvidia have released a beta driver since this which does improve things (for me) but if you can, dropping back to version 295.33 will fix things too (albeit leaving you with the security issue).

If you can survive, hold on with 295.40 until 302.07 hits a PPA (likely `ubuntu-x-swat` will have it first) then install the PPA and upgrade. If you can't wait, you can look for a 295.33 installer (I couldn't find one) or manually install 302.07 from Nvidia's website.

---

**Edit:** A new stable version (295.49) has been released and should hopefully start to trickle through to Ubuntu now.

Comment: I have "Installed: 295.40-0ubuntu1". I suppose my hardware is old. I have two GTX 460 cards. I don't know how to drop back versions or install manually (is it easy?), so I guess I'm stuck with jerky effects...

Comment: I've downloaded the driver on Nvidia's website (295.49), but nothing will run it.